# Algorithm to determine how positive or negative a statement/text is

Tags: c#, algorithm, nlp

I need to implement sentiment analysis.  Can anyone point me to examples/reference implementations?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293000/algorithm-to-determine-how-positive-or-negative-a-statement-text-is

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122595/nlp-qualitatively-positive-vs-negative-sentence and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933212/is-it-possible-to-guess-a-users-mood-based-on-the-structure-of-text

Answer (score 3):

http://www.uclassify.com/
http://www.uclassify.com/browse/prfekt/Mood

Answer (score 2):

One approach is:

1. assemble a corpus of statements and text
2. manually classify each statement as positive or negative
3. ensure your corpus is "large enough" in size, e.g. ~1,000 classifications
4. run the corpus through pattern recognition software such as CRM114: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRM114_(program)
5. use the resulting "brain file" to classify future statements